# Are there any online tools to examine asset allocation and portfolio diversification?

Tags: online-tools, asset-allocation, portfolio, diversification

Are there any good online tools to examine asset allocation, portfolio diversification? I would be interested in being able to plug in numbers, run scenarios etc.

I could build a worksheet in Excel that did this with some kind of pie chart but thought I would avoid a "not invented here" approach and reuse someone's efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a similar quest.

One of the lists I check daily are Google Finances lowest Betas bit.ly/GFscreener12
Shows me a handful of companies with healthy financials and each correlated to the market by 0.33 or less, so it doesn't have to tank along with the S&P 500 as much.

Another using similar criteria but sorted by highest dividend yields:
bit.ly/GFscreener11
To try and keep the results little correlated *to each other*, run that screener once for each of the 12 sectors, for example.

Somewhere I used to use a site that measures and graphs direct correlations. Let me find that link and post back.

[Here](http://www.sectorspdr.com/correlation/)'s one popular Correlation Tracker.

Ah,yes. Remembered the one that's been my favorite: [Impactopedia](http://market-topology.com/index.php?option=com_impactopia&view=friend&Itemid=2)